# How Do I Fix This Sorted Linked List Insertion?

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, insertion-sort

I was given an simple assignment that deals with doubly linked lists, dynamic data allocation, and recursion. I created an array of just 10 integers and I am trying to put these integers into a sorted doubly linked list using recursion. I am having some trouble with inserting nodes into the linked list; my output is "2 7 9 100" and is missing the other 6 integers for some reason. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for any help! (The language used is C)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10

typedef struct node_ {
  int value;
  struct node_ *next;
  struct node_ *prev;
} node;

void insert(node **head, node *cur, node *p);
void print_list(node *cur);


void print_list(node *cur)
{
  if (!cur) {
    printf("\n");
    return;
  } else {
    printf("%d ", cur->value);
    print_list(cur->next);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  int data[N] = {2, 7, 3, 9, 4, 4, 0, 8, 7, 100};
  node *p, *head;
  head = NULL;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    p = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    p->value = data[i];
    insert(&head, head, p);
  }

  print_list(head);
}

void insert(node **head, node *cur, node *p)
{
  if(*head == NULL) 
  {
     p->next = p->prev = NULL;
    *head = p;
    return; 
  }
  if(p->value < cur->value)
  {
    p->prev = cur->prev;
    p->next = cur;
    cur->prev = p;
    if(cur->prev != NULL) 
      cur->prev->next = p;
    else
      *head = p; 
    return; 
  }
  if(cur->next == NULL) 
  {
    cur->next = p;
    p->next = NULL;
    p->prev = cur;
  }
  else 
    insert(head, cur->next, p);
}
```

Comment: Run your program in a debugger and look at your list after each insert. Or print your list after each insert. These are just some simple suggested debugging techniques. You will do well for yourself in the long run if you persevere to debug such basic issues rather than turning to help so easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
cur->prev = p;
if(cur->prev != NULL)
```

That if is never going to be false since you already lost the value of `cur->prev`.

You need to save `cur->prev` into a temporary variable and use that in the if statement, or do the assignment after the if.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem exactly